# Is it possible use a Javascript variable as an index for a Python List in a Flask Template?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

On the last line is `pic_list` is the python list. Is it possible to index the Python list using a javascript variable within a Flask Jinja2 template?

```
function moveright(cur_pos, list_length) {
  if (current_position !== -9999) {
    current_position = cur_pos;
  }
  if (current_position < list_length - 1) {
    current_position = current_position + 1;
  } else {
    current_position = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('image').src = {
    {
      pic_list[current_position]
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: The javascript  is going to run long after (and in a different environment) than the python. One solution might be to define a javascript array literal in the template with the contents of `pic_list`, and refer to than in the js function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Why don't you try to pass the Python list over to JavaScript by converting the collection into a JSON string?

1.Use the `json.dumps()` method to convert the list into a JSON string.

```
@app.route('/test')
def custom_view():
    pic_list = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple']
    return render_template('index.html', data=json.dumps(pic_list))
```

2.Pass the JSON string to the template

```
<script>
    console.log({{ data|safe }});
</script>
```

You **SHOULD AVOID** this procedure if the collection contains [user-supplied data](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/security/#cross-site-scripting-xss).